# How to draw probabilistic distributions with numpy/matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to draw probabilistic functions (like the binomial distribution), but i don't find a function that returns the probability for given parameters. To write it myself i need binomial coefficients (I could write that myself), for which I haven't found a function either. Is there a 'short and/or easy' to do this?
To clarify: I don't want to draw histograms, and I dont want to fit a line to one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`scipy.stats.binom.pmf` gives the probability mass function for the binomial distribution. You could compute it for a range and plot it. for example, for 10 trials, and p = 0.1, you could do

```
import scipy, scipy.stats
x = scipy.linspace(0,10,11)
pmf = scipy.stats.binom.pmf(x,10,0.1)
import pylab
pylab.plot(x,pmf)
```

Comment: Note: the scipy reference states scipy.stats.binom.pdf (probality density function)